# Is there a way to display long statistical test results in two lines using ggstatsplot::grouped_gbetweenstats?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggstatsplot

I am performing an statistical analysis with a set of data grouped by two factors using ggstatsplot::grouped_gbetweenstats, but I have a problem with the results of statistical tests displayed as subtitles, because they are too long and i cannot see all the parameters to save the figure as a pdf in markdown. Lower letter size is not an option, because it is so small and I cannot read it. Is there any option to write it in two lines? Any other ideas are welcome.
Thank you all in advance!

```
WORK <- data.frame(
Sex=factor(c("Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male")),
Genotype=factor(c("KO","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","KO","KO","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","Ctrl","KO","KO","KO","KO","Ctrl","KO","Ctrl","KO")),
Distance=c(42.055,32.483,34.371,40.698,46.138,NA,44.200,NA,47.039,45.958,31.253,43.530,44.544,44.532,39.325,51.660,41.384,NA,31.515,32.778,45.320,41.917,40.653,41.312,37.068,41.881,32.235,41.993,47.173,34.693,43.563,36.802,35.987,38.248,46.707,48.737,32.341,36.214,47.761,35.663,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)
grouped_ggbetweenstats(data = WORK, x=Genotype, y=Distance, grouping.var = Sex, 
                   type= "parametric", var.equal = F, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", 
                   bf.message = F, centrality.label.args=list(size = 2, nudge_x = 0.4, segment.linetype = 4),
                   point.args=list(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.8), alpha=.7, size=3),
                   ggplot.component = list(theme_classic(),
                                           theme(text = element_text(size=12, family = 'Helvetica', color= "black"), legend.position = 'none'),
                                           scale_y_continuous(limits = c(30,50)))
                   )
```